# Can't open Object Arraylist with fileio function

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

*I'm trying to use a function to open an arraylist of objects with fileIO but right now i'm stuck. I think there is something wrong with my setter function. (The file test.txt already exists)*

The following classes I'm using to get the fileio function to work

**Paslijst**

```
public class Paslijst implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<Pas> paslijst;

    public ArrayList<Pas> setPaslijst(ArrayList<Pas> paslijst){
    this.paslijst = paslijst;
    return paslijst;
 }
```

**FileIOPas**

```
// This function opens a file
public Paslijst openen(String filenaam) 
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filenaam);
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream); 
    return (Paslijst) objectInputStream.readObject();
}
```

**Main**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 FileIOPas fileiopas = new FileIOPas();
 Paslijst paslijst = new Paslijst();

 try {
       paslijst.setPaslijst(fileiopas.openen("test.txt"));
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(" IO openen mislukt, want: " + e.toString());
        } 
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("class not found: " + e.toString());
        }
     }
```

Comment: (1) Is your `Pas` class Serializable? (2) What is happening when you run the code?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: What is the problem and what exceptions are you getting?

Comment: @Aleks G Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: beefreeznew.Paslijst.setPaslijst at beefreeznew.BeeFreezNew.main

Yes Pas is a Serializable class.

Comment: You need to fix your compiler error. Nothing to do with opening, or fileio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were passing wrong arguments in paslijst.setPaslijst().I have edited your class may this could Help.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         FileIOPas fileiopas = new FileIOPas();
         Paslijst paslijst = new Paslijst();
         paslijst.setPaslijst(fileiopas.openen("test.txt"));
    }
}

public class FileIOPas {

    public ArrayList<Pas> openen(String filenaam) {

        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filenaam);
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                        fileInputStream);) {
            return (ArrayList<Pas>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

public class Paslijst implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Pas> paslijst;

    public ArrayList<Pas> getPaslijst() {
        return paslijst;
    }

    public void setPaslijst(ArrayList<Pas> paslijst) {
        this.paslijst = paslijst;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i realized that myself too but thanks for speeding up the proces.